# Why does my derivation of K.E seem correct but not agree with the formula of K.E?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, kinematics, work

We know that

$$\vec{F}=m\vec{a}$$

$$Work = \vec{F}\cdot\vec{S}$$ where $\vec{S}$ is the displacement.

So, we have,
$$W = m\vec{a}\cdot \vec{S} = \frac{m(\vec{v}-\vec{u})}{t}\cdot \vec{S}$$

Assuming object started out at rest,
$$W = \frac{m\vec{v}}{t}\cdot \vec{S}$$
Since $\vec{v}=\frac{\vec{S}}{t}$,
 $$W=m\frac{\vec{S}^2}{t^2}$$
$$W=m(\frac{\vec{S}^2}{t^2}) = mv^2$$

However work is $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ not just $mv^2$. What is happening? What's wrong?

Comment: Do you know the concept of integration?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.